# How to control double precision computing to avoid rounding errors in C++ linux x86_64?

Tags: c++, algorithm, double, precision, rounding-error

In a C++ code on linux x86_64, I need to double precision computing (+ or -).

26.100000000000001 - 26 + 0.10000000000000001

I got:

0.20000000000000143

I want to get 0.2.

here, the display format is not import, the computing results will be used for some if-else branch conditions. So, I only want the if-else conditions compare the 4 digits after the decimal digit.

It seems a rounding error ?

How to restrict the computing precision to 4 digits after decimal point ?

I do not want to call any functions in order to avoid overhead.

I do not want to use stringstream due to transformation overhead.

Any better ideas ?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The computing precision is fine. It's the *display precision* you're trying to control. You can do that with `setprecision()` if using `<iostream>` or a formatter like `"%.4f"` if using `<stdio.h>`.

*You are already calling functions since you are **displaying the result as decimal!***

P.S. `0.1` cannot be exactly represented by a `float`, `double`, or any binary-mantissa format. It factors into `(1/2) * (1/5)`, and decimal `1/5` is an infinitely-repeating digit sequence in binary.

P.P.S. Go look at [GMP](http://gmplib.org/). It might be your best hope.

Comment: here, the display format is not import, the computing results will be used for some if-else branch conditions. So, I only want the if-else conditions compare the 4 digits after the decimal digit.

Comment: @user1002288 What you're trying to do is not possible with binary floating-point. No amount of rounding hacks will make decimal arithmetic on binary floating-point work like magic..

Comment: @user1002288 You can just add some magic `epsilon` value to all you floating-precision comparisons. Like `if (a==b) {}` transforms into `if (abs(a-b) < 1e-4) {}`. This is the best thing you can do using floating-point arithmetics.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print it it, you can use printf("%10.4lf"). You can alter the precision to anything you want, of course.

Comment: here, the display format is not import, the computing results will be used for some if-else branch conditions. So, I only want the if-else conditions compare the 4 digits after the decimal digit.

Comment: oh you mean display format is not importANT! ok.. you can try multiplying with 10^(precision) [precision=4 in your case].

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in equality up to four decimal places, multiply everything by 10,000 and use integer arithmetic. (You might need to round after multiplying by 10,000.)